# Не подключаются файлы к теме WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Помогите новичку с проблемой. Проблема состоит в том что вроде бы все в файле functions.php все правильно подключил, но нет. Проверил на ошибки в корне но их тоже нет, помогите я в тупике(((

Ниже предоставлен код файла functions.php

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'My_theme_scripts' );
function My_theme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-css', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style('animate', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/animate.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome.min.css' );

    //wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );

    
}
?>
```

[image: коды ошибок]

[image: пути файлов]

Comment: Ошибки в консоли есть? Проверил ваш код он работает, возможно в контексте другого кода работать не будет.

Comment: Тема основная или дочерняя?

Comment: если дочерняя, то get_stylesheet_uri() - дает путь к дочерней теме, а get_template_directory_uri() даст путь к родительской. проверить существуют ли файлы по этим путям. проверить по пересечению названий стилей

Comment: Тема основная. в консоли след. ошибка:Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: не подключается bootstrap.min.css;animate.min.css;font-awesome.min.css;

Comment: файлы существуют и путь точно указан но ошибка не исправляется (

Comment: В коде ошибок нет. Значит это либо тема дочерняя, либо эта тема вообще не подключена. Посмотрите в админке какая активная тема.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

У вас во всех строках прописан get_template_directory_uri() а его нужно прописывать только для дефолтного style.css.
Подключение должно выглядить вот так

```
<?php
        function My_theme_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'style-css', get_stylesheet_uri() );
        wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', '/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
        wp_enqueue_style('animate', '/css/animate.min.css' );
        wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome', '/css/font-awesome.min.css' );
    
        //wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );   
    }
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'My_theme_scripts' );

    ?>
```

Comment: Ну вообще-то нет) В том примере который Вы привели, эти папки будет искать внутри корневого каталога сайта,  а не внутри темы) Убедиться в том что `get_template_directory_uri()` необходим, можно проверив [документацию](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_enqueue_style)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать более "современное" решение в виде функции `get_theme_file_uri()`:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'My_theme_scripts' );
function My_theme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-css', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_theme_file_uri( 'css/bootstrap.min.css' ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'animate', get_theme_file_uri( 'css/animate.min.css' ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome', get_theme_file_uri( 'css/font-awesome.min.css' ) );
}
?>
```